# PHP Zend Framework S3 - PutFile not putting

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3

I'm simply trying to loop through a folder of images and put them in an Amazon S3 bucket. I just can't figure out why it doesn't like the DATA part of the PUTFILE function.

If I try:

```
$res = $s3 -> putFile("test-bucket/".$entry);
```

It creates a blank file (0 bytes) in the bucket, so I know it's connecting OK, and the filenames are correct also. I've also tried looping through the folders files and echoing the filenames to the screen, without using the Zend S3 function, which proved this page can access the files behind root.

The [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html) regarding this function says:

> putFile($path, $object, $meta) puts the content of the file in $path
>   into the object named $object.
>
> The optional $meta argument is the same as for putObject. If the
>   content type is omitted, it will be guessed basing on the source file
>   name.

This is what I've tried:

```
if ($handle = opendir('d:/web-library-photos/temp-previews')) {

    $loopCounter = 0;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        ///
        $loopCounter = $loopCounter + 1;
        if ($loopCounter < 3) { // for test purposes only
            $localPath = "d:/web-library-photos/temp-previews/".$entry;
            $s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($aws_access_key_id, $aws_s3_secret);
            $res = $s3 -> putFile($localPath, "test-bucket/".$entry);
            echo "Success for ".$entry.": " . ($res ? 'Yes' : 'No') . "<br>";
        }
        ///
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

This particular "try" yields the error:

```
Cannot read file d:/web-library-photos/temp-previews/.' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\.....thispage.php
```

So I thought I would try **file_get_contents()** and **readfile()** but still no luck!

Please, please, put me straight on this one - it's driving me round the bend.

**UPDATE**

Right, I have a clue what's wrong but not how to solve it.

If I simply do this:

```
if ($handle = opendir('d:/web-library-photos/temp-previews')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo $entry."<BR>";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

I get a `.` and a `..` at the beginning of my results, which obviously can't be read as filenames!! What is going on here, how do I get around it?

[image]

Comment: `.` and `..` are current and parent directories and you need to ignore them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to append this in `while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))`

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {  
    if($entry == "." || $entry == "..") continue;
    /* other codes */
}
```

Comment: I didn't get your exact answer working but got one very similar to it working. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: I'm not sure why I accepted your answer cos it didn't solve the main issue. you helped me get rid of the . and .. but still have same issues. thanks for first part :)

Comment: What is your updated code? :), looks like you did it wrong. I just mean echo the content, to check whatever php can access the data. Not giving the result to freamework.

Comment: It works now, sorry for confusion. I was still using file_get_contents and I didn't need it.